# Index out of bounds error when parsing to Integer

Tags: java, parsing, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting an error when trying to parse from a `String` to an `Integer` or a `double`.

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(stringParts[2]);
```

If I print `stringParts[2]` it works, it only throws an error when parsing.

This is the complete loop I'm using:

```
  public static StudentRecord[] creates(String fileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/DNA40/Desktop/lab11input.txt"));
    int lineText = lineCount("/Users/DNA40/Desktop/lab11input.txt");
    String record;
    String cons = ("[ ]");

    StudentRecord[] student = new StudentRecord[lineText]; 

    String[] stringParts = new String[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < lineText ; i++){


        student[i] = new StudentRecord();//Creates Object class
        record = br.readLine(); //Stores the first line of text file

        stringParts = record.split("\\s+");//Splits the line into parts
        student[i].setFirstName(stringParts[0]);
        student[i].setLastName(stringParts[1]);
        int id = Integer.parseInt(stringParts[2]);
        student[i].setID(id);
        double gpa = Double.parseDouble(stringParts[3]);
        student[i].setGPA(gpa);
        int hours = Integer.parseInt(stringParts[4]);
        student[i].setHours(hours);


        }


        return student;
    }






public static int lineCount(String fileName) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    int count = 0;
    String currentLine;



    while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
        count++;

    }



    return count;
}
```

It generates error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2`

Thank you

Comment: Integer.parseInt should not throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, that can only come from an array! the stacktrace would be useful

Comment: What's the length of `student`? `student.length` and  `lineText` might be different...

Comment: What is lineText? What is it's value during the loop?

Comment: I added more code. lineText is the number of lines in the text file, which is two.

Comment: Don't believe it's the actual code, because this one runs perfectly fine.

Comment: @DNA40 Actually try printing the data contained in the stringParts array after you assign the split. It seems to be returning to you an Array smaller than what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Index out of bounds means that

```
stringParts[2]
```

does not exist. Check the length of the array. The split probably isent working as you would expect